# deleting orphan record - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, laravel

I have following tables

```
question
-------------------
id | name

quiz_results
------------------
id|question_id|is_correct
```

Accidentally i deleted some question from the backend
Note: I have used laravel framework and used model to maintain dependency. I havent used any relationship on database level.
Now i need to remove the orphan records from quiz_results(i.e i need to delete those records whose question was deleted accidentally)

I tried below

```
delete from quiz_results where id IN (SELECT qr.id
FROM  `quiz_results` qr
LEFT JOIN questions q ON ( q.id = qr.question_id ) 
WHERE q.id IS NULL )
```

it is  giving following error

## 1093 - You can't specify target table 'quiz_results' for update in FROM clause

Earlier I also tried without subquery like below

```
delete from
FROM  `quiz_results` qr
LEFT JOIN questions q ON ( q.id = qr.question_id ) 
WHERE q.id IS NULL
```

which throw the syntax error

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM `quiz_results` qr LEFT JOIN questions q ON ( q.id = qr.question_id ) WH' at line 2**

Comment: You don't need the subquery - the LEFT JOIN will do what you want. But you could also look at referential integrity in the form a CASCADE ON DELETE statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the follwing query:
DELETE FROM quiz_results WHERE question_id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM question)

Comment: Aesthetically, I like the OP's solution better. I guess I'm just old-fashioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
delete from quiz_results r 
where not exists 
    (
        select 1 
        from question q 
        where q.id=r.question_id
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from FROM `quiz_results`
```

-->

```
delete `quiz_results` FROM  `quiz_results`
```